# Is there an equivalent of ExcelWriter in PySpark?

Tags: excel, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am exporting my dataframe to an Excel and conditionally formatting it with colors (So no PyExcelerate for me) and what takes the most time by far is the conversion toPandas, i was wondering if there is a way to do it with the spark dataframe, the code is this:

```
    excel_writer_global = pd.ExcelWriter("excel_output.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    # Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
    print_seconds_since_start("To pandas")
    pd_df_a_escribir = df_a_escribir.toPandas()
    print_seconds_since_start("Fin to pandas")
    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    pd_df_a_escribir.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=name_hoja)
    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook  = excel_writer.book
    worksheet = excel_writer.sheets[name_hoja]
```

It would have to be a quicker solution as that is the problem right now,
thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If your data fits in an excel sheet, this mean it can fit on the spark driver. Thus you can collect it to Pandas and use the later to write it in excel.

Comment: eliasah isnt that what i am already doing? My problem is "df_a_escribir.toPandas()" takes 60% of the total time from start to end.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the details of the question. There is a library that doesn't that with spark but it's an overkill (https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) for the reasons I've mentioned above. i.e if your data is to big to fit in an excel, it shouldn't be in an excel.

Comment: You could just skip the pandas step and write directly to Excel using the XlsxWriter or OpenPyXL apis.

Comment: @jmcnamara I believe that with taking time is collection all the data back to the spark driver (that's what `toPandas()` does).